# How to push code to an org using a CCI command?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, selenium, cumulusci

I am trying to run a robot test on CircleCI using the command `cci task run robot`, but it is creating the fresh org again as it executes.
How can I push the code to a newly created org?

This is the full command: `venv/bin/cci task run robot -o suites robot/xxxxx/testst.robot -o include test -o vars LocalOrRemote:Local,Browser:googlechrome --org dev`

Answer (score 2):

[CumulusCI](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/) executes commands against the org whose name you specify with `--org`. If that org does not yet exist, CumulusCI creates an empty org and executes the command against it.

Before running tests, whether Robot or Apex, with CumulusCI, you'll typically build the org using a flow, such as `dev_org`, `qa_org`, or `install_beta`. Those flows push your project's unmanaged code into the org (`dev_org` and `qa_org`), or install a managed beta (`install_beta`). For Robot tests, it's common to do something like

```
cci flow run qa_org --org dev
cci task run robot --org dev [...]
```

That builds the org first and then runs Robot tests against it.

If you think you've already built the org, perhaps you run the building flow in a different CircleCI container than you're running the `robot` task? If that's the case, your CumulusCI in the Robot context may not have access to the details of the created org, and you'd need to persist it using Circle's [workspaces](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#persist_to_workspace) feature.

*(Disclosure: I am on the team that builds CumulusCI at Salesforce.org)*.

Comment: I am able to push the code, But it is creating new org again in _cci task run robot --org dev_ I am using below command                                                        _venv/bin/cci flow run qa_org --org dev
                 venv/bin/cci task run robot --org dev -o suites robot/tests/Activities.robot -o include test -o vars LocalOrRemote:Local,Browser:googlechrome_

Comment: @PronitAgrawal We'll need to see your CircleCI configuration. That's not how CumulusCI is expected to work. What CCI version are you using?